Weird armature deformation on mech leg
I am trying to learn rigging and I tried to rig this mech there is some weird deformation when I try to move the leg of the mech

I don’t really know how to fix this. As I am new to this is there anybody who can help me?
You can download the model file here

Select the vertices that are not supposed to move and remove them from all groups:

Then assign them to the correct vertex group:

